# how to use createAsyncThunk correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Anyone with redux toolkit knowledge? The code below is causing my entire app to crash. Can anyone spot the problem in my asyncThunk because I can't...

```
export const getBarbers = createAsyncThunk(
  "/barbers/fetchBarbers",
  async () => {
    return fetch("/api/barbers").then((res) => res.json());
  }
);
```

Removing the async keyword remedies the app failure but I'm pretty sure I need that.

Comment: This code looks fine. What do you mean about "crash"? Is there any error?

Comment: No error message but my app won't render unless I take the async keyword out

Comment: If I compare it to how I use it, I only spot two differences:
1. Your `createAsyncThunk` parameter starts with a `/`, mine doesn't.
2. Your return is a Promise, mine is `await fetch...`. If I had to pick the culprit, it would probably be the first one, so change it to `barbers/fetchBarbers` and you should be fine.

Comment: I think we need more context, and by your admission removing the `async` declaration it seems to work, we need to see how this action is being used and dispatched to understand what is occurring. Besides that, you are mixing `async/await` syntax with Promise chains, a common anti-pattern. Since your thunk doesn't wait for anything to resolve and simply returns the `fetch` Promise you should either (1) remove `async` and move along, or (2) wrap the `fetch` in a `try/catch` and `await` it and the `json` to resolve and return the data.